# creating nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to create a nested dictionary in such a form:

```
{
    catagory_name: {1: abc, 2: efg},
    category_name: {1: pqr, 2: stu},
    category_name: {1: vwx, 2: ijk, 3: lmn}
}
```

Where I will fetch `category1_name`, `category2_name` and `category3_name` from a table1 and then I will for loop it to execute new query and fetch values `abc, efg, pqr, stu` and `vwx, ijk, lmn` from next table based on Ids fetched from table1.

Something like this:

```
categories = cat.getAllCatagories()

for value in categories:
    categoriesData = {}
    subCategories = cat.getSubCategoriesByCategoryId(value.id)
    for val in subCategories:
        categoriesData[values.name] = val.name

context = {'categoriesData': categoriesData}

return render(request, 'demo/test/industries_catagories.html', context)
```

Now I want to access this categoriesData dictionary in my template of Django framework and list it form of tree structure.

Any ideas will be very much appreciated.

Sources I referred [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries) are very complicated.

Comment: Pasting the dictionary you provide as an example, in a python shell errors are raised. If I try to correct them, the result is something different from your example.

Comment: @raratiru Can you please paste that result here?

Comment: a dictionary(or dict for short) is a key value pair. Meaning that each key have a value. Therefor the keys must be unique. You have three keys with the same name: catagory_name. Consider having your key like so: catagory_name_1, catagory_name_2, catagory_name_3.

Comment: @DanielHeidemann explained well, but there is also a typo which makes the situation worse: `{'catagory_name': {1: 'abc', 2: 'efg'},
 'category_name': {1: 'vwx', 2: 'ijk', 3: 'lmn'}}`. The issue is that if you know exactly what you are looking, complex structures might become self-explanatory.