# problem loading Autovivification file when moving from python 2.7 to 3.6, KeyError: 'DictType'

Tags: python, dictionary, autovivification

In python 2.7, I have a bunch of files stored as the following object:

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value
```

This is from [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries).

I have them pickled and can load them just fine. But in python 3.6, it gives me the following error when trying to load the same file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 577, in _load_type
    return _reverse_typemap[name]
KeyError: 'DictType'
```

I'm using the following line of code to load the object:

```
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    return pickle.load(f)
```

how do I use python 3.6 to load the file?

Comment: There are incompatibilities in pickle.  Try a search on here and you'll find several different problems and resolutions.

Comment: i don't think it is a pickle issue. because i saved them as pickle in protocol 2, so if i use python 3.6 it should be protocol 3 and it should be able to read protocol 2. I tried the other way (saving in pickle 3 and loading in pickle 2 and got an error that I easily found a solution for on SO)