# Forward slash subscripting

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for the best way to go about subscripting a multi-layer Python dict with a string containing forward slashes to indicate sub keys. Currently I have something like this:

```
>>> data = {'some': {'key': 'value'}, 'foo': {'bar': 'pow'}}  # data received from an external api
>>> field = 'some/key'  # metadata path received from the same api
>>> for key in field.split('/'):
...     data = data.get(key)
... print(data)
value
```

Comment: If you could use nested objects instead of nested dictionaries, then you could use `.` and access the objects’s properties directly. Then even consider [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (careful with that function, though)… 

Comment: The dict object I receive is from an external source. The one I posted above is just an example.

Comment: Is the use of forward slashes written in stone? If not, then there may be something you can do with jmespath.

Comment: Then consider wrapping the dictionary into an “object view”, something like [this blog](https://goodcode.io/articles/python-dict-object/) describes.

Comment: Yes, it's included in metadata I'm receiving from an external api.

Comment: I would bind the dictionary to a second name and use that in your loop, so that `data` is still the same after accessing the element. Otherwise the solution lokks fine.

Comment: There's no point switching from dicts to something that uses attribute access notation. It just means you end up using `getattr` instead of indexing, and that's no improvement. (That, or you end up with `eval`, which has far too many failure cases to suggest using, and puts a major security hole in your code for no benefit.)

Comment: Is there a reason not to just wrap your current logic in a function and use it?

Comment: I can use a function, I was wondering if there was a more straightforward approach to this.

Comment: The data-structure described and the answers to the question [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries) might help.