# Combobox Binding - Managing the Data

Tags: python, tkinter

Hopefully a quick one but knowing me it won't be.  I am writing a small App for myself, I collect Silver Coins, I will be doing more than silver in the future, but for now I would like to record what I have, the plan is to use Comboboxes to display only data that is required for each subsiquent Combobox

The data that each coin has are (Metal_Type, Country, Coin_Type, Year, Fineness)
As per below, I have a Country list for each Metal_Type (Gold, Silver, Platinum, Pallidium), Each country has at LEAST 1 coin and not all countries do all Metal_Types, some counties have more.  Counting it, there will be at LEAST 54 IF statements for the Combobox Events

Is there a more appropriate way of managing this data,  Dictionaries maybe?

```
{"Australia1": {"Silver": "Red Kangaroo", "Koala", "Kookaburra"}}                                   
{"Australia2": {"Gold": "Gold Nugget", "Dragon Rectangular Coin"}}
{"Australia3": {"Platinum": "coin1", "coin2"}}
```

and so forth

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def draw_main_window():
    metals = ['Palladium',
              'Platinum',
              'Gold',
              'Silver']

    gold_country = ["Austria",
                    "Canada",
                    "China",
                    "Iran",
                    "Isle of Man",
                    "Israel",
                    "Kazakhstan",
                    "Malaysia",
                    "Malta",
                    "Mexico",
                    "New Zealand",
                    "Poland",
                    "Russia",
                    "Somalia",
                    "South Africa",
                    "Ukraine",
                    "United Kingdom",
                    "United States"]

    silver_country = ["Armenia",
                      "Australia",
                      "Austria",
                      "Canada",
                      "China",
                      "Congo (Republic)",
                      "Cook Islands",
                      "Isle of Man",
                      "Mexico",
                      "New Zealand",
                      "Niue/Fiji",
                      "Russia",
                      "Rwanda",
                      "Serbia",
                      "Somalia",
                      "South Africa",
                      "South Korea",
                      "Ukraine",
                      "United Kingdom",
                      "United States"]

    palladium_list = ["Australia",
                      "Canada",
                      "China",
                      "Portugal",
                      "Russia",
                      "United States"]

    platinum_list = ["Australia",
                     "Austria",
                     "Canada",
                     "Isle of Man",
                     "United Kingdom",
                     "United States"]

    def metal_click(event):
        metal_value = cmb_metal.get()

        if metal_value == "Palladium":
            cmb_country['values'] = palladium_list

        if metal_value == "Platinum":
            cmb_country['values'] = platinum_list

        if metal_value == "Gold":
            cmb_country['values'] = gold_country

        if metal_value == "Silver":
            cmb_country['values'] = silver_country

    def country_click(event):
        current_value = cmb_country.get()

        if current_value == "Australia":
            cmb_type['values'] = "Emu"

        if current_value == "Canada":
            cmb_type['values'] = "Palladium Maple Leaf"

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("640x480")
    root.title("Silver-Inventory")

    Label(root, text="Metal").grid(column=0, row=0)
    Label(root, text="Country").grid(column=0, row=1)
    Label(root, text="Coin Type").grid(column=0, row=2)
    Label(root, text="Year").grid(column=0, row=3)
    Label(root, text="Metal").grid(column=0, row=4)
    Label(root, text="Fineness").grid(column=0, row=5)

    cmb_metal = ttk.Combobox(root, values=metals)
    cmb_metal.grid(column=1, row=0)
    cmb_metal.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", metal_click)

    cmb_country = ttk.Combobox(root)
    cmb_country.grid(column=1, row=1)
    cmb_country.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", country_click)

    cmb_type = ttk.Combobox(root)
    cmb_type.grid(column=1, row=2)

    root.mainloop()


draw_main_window()
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a dictionary dispatch

Comment: I've updated the main post, Reading back , it sometimes didn't make any sense

Comment: It made sense to me, and the answer from Bryan Oakley seems the right one for this

Answer (score 0):

You can often convert a long series of `if` statements into a simple dictionary lookup.

For example, instead of this:

```
metal_value = cmb_metal.get()
if metal_value == "Palladium":
    cmb_country['values'] = palladium_list

if metal_value == "Platinum":
    cmb_country['values'] = platinum_list

if metal_value == "Gold":
    cmb_country['values'] = gold_country

if metal_value == "Silver":
    cmb_country['values'] = silver_country
```

... you can use a dictionary to create a mapping between the metal value and the list:

```
mapping = {
    "Palladium": palladium_list,
    "Platinum": platinum_list,
    "Gold": gold_country,
    "Silver": silver_country,
}
metal_value = cmb_metal.get()
cmb_country['values'] = mapping[metal_value]
```

Comment: I would let the 'values' be `lambda: cmb_country.config(values=palladium_list)` and then call the function, and this type of mapping is called dictionary dispatch

Answer (score 0):

I think nested dictionaries would be the good way to do it. I've always liked @Aaron Hall's `Vividict` class shown in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19829714/355230) to the question [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries) because it makes it so easy to construct them. The concept comes from Perl and is called [*autovivification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).

Here's a demonstration of how it might be used to hold the kind of data you have:

```
from pprint import pprint

# Quick and dirty way to define a bunch of constant strings to make it
# unnecessary to quote them in the code every place they are used.
namespace = globals()
for name in ("Gold Silver Platinum "
             "Armenia Austria Australia Canada China Isle_of_Man "
             "Coin1 Coin2 Coin3 Coin4".split()):
    namespace[name] = name


class Vividict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value


data = {(Gold, Austria): [Coin1, Coin2],
        (Gold, Canada): [Coin1, Coin2, Coin3],
        (Gold, China): [Coin1, Coin2],
        (Silver, Armenia): [Coin1, Coin2],
        (Silver, Australia): [Coin1, Coin2],
        (Platinum, Australia): [Coin1],
        (Platinum, Austria): [Coin1, Coin2, Coin3],
        (Platinum, Canada): [Coin1, Coin2, Coin3, Coin4],
        (Platinum, Isle_of_Man): [Coin1, Coin2]}

d = Vividict()
for (metal, country), coins in data.items():
    d[metal][country] = coins

pprint(d)
```

Here's the nested dictionary that's created:

```
{'Gold': {'Austria': ['Coin1', 'Coin2'],
          'Canada': ['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3'],
          'China': ['Coin1', 'Coin2']},
 'Platinum': {'Australia': ['Coin1'],
              'Austria': ['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3'],
              'Canada': ['Coin1', 'Coin2', 'Coin3', 'Coin4'],
              'Isle_of_Man': ['Coin1', 'Coin2']},
 'Silver': {'Armenia': ['Coin1', 'Coin2'], 'Australia': ['Coin1', 'Coin2']}}
```