# Convert nested CSV data to json

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv that is in the following format:

```
p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9
u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,u6,u7,u8,u9
10,500,10,10,6.192187,0,0,10.3313,8.58659
2,150,5,3,6.7125,8.497266,9.130859,6.46657,7.645142111
,,,4,6.960938,9.472656,,6.64784,8.060439698
,,,5,7.819531,0,0,6.88975,8.972818303
```

where 'p' represents properties and 'u' represents units.
Note that there are missing values when subsequent values
are the same for that column. Unfortunately I cannot pad them.

My aim is to convert the csv to JSON using python.
The format should be something like the following structure:

```
val1:{
      val2:{
        val3:{ [val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9]
                    }}}

val1:{
      val2:{
        val3:{ [val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9],
               [val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9],
               [val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9],
                 }}}
```

Note that the first two lines can be ignored.
I have the following python code to start with :

```
import csv
import json
 
 
# Function to convert a CSV to JSON
# Takes the file paths as arguments


def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
 
    # create a dictionary
    data = {}
 
    # Open a csv reader called DictReader
    with open(csvFilePath,  mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf,delimiter =',')

    for rows in csvReader:
        # Assuming a column named 'p1' to
        # be the primary key
        key = rows['p1']
        data[key] = rows
    
# Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()
# function to dump data
with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
    jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
     
# Driver Code
 
# Decide the two file paths according to your
# computer system
csvFilePath = r'./data/chart-0.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'./js/try.js'

 
# Call the make_json function
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: What are you representing via the trailing backslash characters on the lines of the csv file? How do you want the first two lines handled?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. Editing now. The first two lines should be in the same format.

Comment: OK. How do you want those first two processed?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the column names as keys of the dictionary, but for simplicity, we can ignore them for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want if I've understood what's implied by the desired output format shown in your question with regards to handling the missing values.

```
import csv
import json


# Function to convert a CSV to JSON
# Takes the file paths as arguments
def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):

    # create a dictionary
    data = {}

    # Open and read with a csv reader.
    with open(csvFilePath,  mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter =',')
        next(csvReader); next(csvReader)  # Skip first 2 rows.
        prev_key = None
        for row in csvReader:
            key = row[0:3]
            if not all(key):  # If keys missing, use previous key.
                data[prev_key[0]][prev_key[1]][prev_key[2]].append(row[4:])
            else:
                data.setdefault(key[0], {}).setdefault(key[1], {}).setdefault(key[2], [])
                data[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]].append(row[4:])
                prev_key = key

    # Open a json writer, and use the json.dumps()
    # function to dump data
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


# Driver Code

# Decide the two file paths according to your
# computer system
csvFilePath = 'chart-0.csv'
jsonFilePath = 'try.json'


# Call the make_json function
make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

Contents of JSON output file after running:

```
{
    "10": {
        "500": {
            "10": [
                [
                    "6.192187",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "10.3313",
                    "8.58659"
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "150": {
            "5": [
                [
                    "6.7125",
                    "8.497266",
                    "9.130859",
                    "6.46657",
                    "7.645142111"
                ],
                [
                    "6.960938",
                    "9.472656",
                    "",
                    "6.64784",
                    "8.060439698"
                ],
                [
                    "7.819531",
                    "0",
                    "0",
                    "6.88975",
                    "8.972818303"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help. One additional question - Similar to nesting from var1 column, how can I nest  from other columns? Say from var2 or var3, under the same var group?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be possible by generalizing what the code in my answer is doing. There are ways of creating nested dictionaries that will automatically create each level the first time it's referenced — kind of like a `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s if that means anything to you. Dictionaries nested like this are sometimes called "trees".

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: See [What is the best way to implement nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635483/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-nested-dictionaries) for some more insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert .csv to .json, use pandas and json

First of all, we would convert csv to  dictionary and then dict to json

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

file = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
print(json.dumps(file.to_dict(), indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "p1": {
        "0": "u1",
        "1": "10",
        "2": "2",
        "3": NaN,
        "4": NaN
    },
    "p2": {
        "0": "u2",
        "1": "500",
        "2": "150",
        "3": NaN,
        "4": NaN
    },
    "p3": {
        "0": "u3",
        "1": "10",
        "2": "5",
        "3": NaN,
        "4": NaN
    },
    "p4": {
        "0": "u4",
        "1": "10",
        "2": "3",
        "3": "4",
        "4": "5"
    },
    "p5": {
        "0": "u5",
        "1": "6.192187",
        "2": "6.7125",
        "3": "6.960938",
        "4": "7.819531"
    },
    "p6": {
        "0": "u6",
        "1": "0",
        "2": "8.497266",
        "3": "9.472656",
        "4": "0"
    },
    "p7": {
        "0": "u7",
        "1": "0",
        "2": "9.130859",
        "3": NaN,
        "4": "0"
    },
    "p8": {
        "0": "u8",
        "1": "10.3313",
        "2": "6.46657",
        "3": "6.64784",
        "4": "6.88975"
    },
    "p9": {
        "0": "u9",
        "1": "8.58659",
        "2": "7.645142111",
        "3": "8.060439698",
        "4": "8.972818303"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is close, though @martineau achieved the closest solution. I appreciate your help!! -Luis

Comment: welcome buddy :)